# Production when create json file got Error 500 internal server error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

On localhost create json file no problem but on production create json file got error code 500 internal server error. Why I got error and how can I fix?

Code jquery

```
            var url = '@Url.Action("CreateJsonFileContent", "xxx")';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(content),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            }).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("Status : " + textStatus);
            })
```

Code Controller (Some part)

```
        [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CreateJsonFileContent(string PlantName, List<string> EmailName)
    {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contents);
            
            string pathFile = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pathJson"];
            string jsonPath = Path.Combine(pathFile + "\\" +  PlantName.Replace(" ", "") + ".json");

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(jsonPath)) System.IO.File.Delete(jsonPath);

            using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(jsonPath))
            {
                tw.WriteLine(json);
            }
            return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       
    }
```

Comment: What exception is being logged when the 500 occurs? Have you debugged it?

Comment: The issue is in your controller (back end), not in you javascript (front end). I'm going to guess it's a file access issue. You need to enable logging to work out why your controller is throwing the 500 error

Answer (score 1):

Like [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1690193/nick-mcdermaid) guessed, your web application most likely do not have permissions to perform file operations or it is attempting to access (read from and/or write to) a location that does not exist.

One way to know what is happening for sure is for you to have logging enabled and active on the production server. Another (but potentially very insecure way) is to add a try-catch statement to the controller method and put all the IO operations inside that try-catch statement (see example below).

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CreateJsonFileContent(string PlantName, List<string> EmailName)
    {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contents);
            
            string pathFile = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pathJson"];
            string jsonPath = Path.Combine(pathFile + "\\" +  PlantName.Replace(" ", "") + ".json");


            try
            {
               if (System.IO.File.Exists(jsonPath)) System.IO.File.Delete(jsonPath);

                using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(jsonPath))
                {
                   tw.WriteLine(json);
                }
                return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // log error here
                return Json(new
                {
                     message = "An error occurred while creating the file",
                     details = ex.ToString()
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }           
    }
```

The reason I call it potentially very insecure is that you're exposing the details of the server errors to the end user. This should **never** be allowed in my opinion. That being said, using the try-catch statement to gracefully handle possible exceptions like the one you're getting is a good practice.

Other than that, if you have the relevant access on the production server, you can attempt to grant the application (and the user that is executing it) permissions to access said location.